# SessionScoped not working GAE+Jersey+Guice

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jersey, guice, session-scope

I have a Java project where I use Jersey (1.17) and Guice (3.0). SessionScoped beans work in local dev, but don't work when deployed on GAE. The problem is that they don't keep session state.

Sessions are enabled in web.xml: `<sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>`

My Session bean (SessionService) is:

```
@SessionScoped
public class SessionService implements Serializable {
    @Inject transient Logger log;
    private Locale locale = Locale.US;
    public synchronized Locale getLocale() { return locale; }
    public synchronized void setLocale(Locale locale) { this.locale = locale; }
}
```

and it's bound to Session scope in ServletModule `bind(SessionService.class).in(ServletScopes.SESSION);`

Controller where I use it is:

```
@Path("/settings")  
public class SettingsController {
    @Inject SessionService sessionService;

    @GET
    @Path("/setLocale")
    public Object setLocale(@QueryParam("languageTag") String languageTag) {
        sessionService.setLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag(languageTag));
        return "OK";
    }

     @GET
    @Path("/getLocale")
    public Object getLocale() { return sessionService.getLocale().getLanguage(); }
}
```

With local dev server it works fine. When deployed on GAE (1.9.5) it sets the locale the first time and then it stays the same forever even though I call setLocale again and again. Why does it not work ?

Strangely enough, I found an obscure way to make it work, but I don't know why it makes it work. To have it running, it's necessary to touch HttpSession before setting locale. Like `request.getSession(true).setAttribute("whatever", "bar")`. As if server needed to be recalled that SessionService wants to do something with Session. Why is that?

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same problem.
I'm using GAE 1.9.10, Guice 3.0 but no Jersey.
Did figure this out?

Comment: as i have that workaround i didn't experiment further. i'd be happy to find out how to do it properly though.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way how to get desired SessionScoped-like functionality. Don't use `@SessionScoped` as it apparently does not work on GAE, but instead use `Provider<HttpSession>`.

So your code will be like

```
public class SessionService {
    @Inject Provider<HttpSession> httpSessionProvider;

    public void saveSecurityInfo(Object securityInfo) {
        httpSessionProvider.get().setAttribute('sec_info', securityInfo);
    }

    public Object loadSecurityInfo() {
        return httpSessionProvider.get().getAttribute('sec_info');
    }
}
```

In controller you'd insert it as `@Inject SessionService sessionService;`

I've tested this approach on GAE and it works (keeps information in browser session).